# Edit specific letter colour using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

When I write in the textbox the text I have written will be output to the `<p>`. However, I want all my letter `b`, `p` or `d` to be output in a different colour. For example `i like to drink beer` the letter `d` and `b` must be of different colours. Any help how to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('welcome');
  $('button').click(function() {
    var myText = $('input:text').val();
    $('p').html(myText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Place you text here =)" />
<button>Click me</button>

<p></p>
```

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan told, text within input can't have many colors. You can show colorful text in P through using regexp and manipulating the input. In dynamic text perspective, in "i like to drink beer" every first letter, or 1st letter of any word will have different color. Not only d and b will have different color as you want.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      
function rep_str(str, str_find, color) {
 var reg = new RegExp(str, 'gi');
 var final_str = str_find.replace(reg, function(str) {return str.fontcolor(color)});
 return final_str;
}

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            var myText=$('input[type="text"]').val();
            myText = rep_str("b|d", myText, "Blue");
            myText = rep_str("p", myText, "Red");
            $('p').html(myText);

        });
    });
    </script>
    <body>

    <input type="text" value="i like to drink beer" />
    <button>Click me</button>

    <p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you could use a regular expression to search for the relevant characters in the string and wrap them in a `span` element which can be styled however you require. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var myText = $('input:text').val();
    $('p').html(myText.replace(/(b|d|p)/gi, '<span>$1</span>'));
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Place you text here =)" value="Vestibulum imperdiet malesuada elit" />
<button>Click me</button>

<p></p>
```